# remove unwanted directories from collection of all directoies: android?

Tags: java, android, directory, set

I want to remove all directories from the scanned result except my required directory. I think in "folders" all directories are listed, from that i need to extract my folder "chatter". the folder "chatter" may stored in internal/external storage! Can anybody help me please..??

```
public void startScan() {
    clearData();
    final LibSettings libSettings = LibSettings.current();
    final Set<String> folders = new LinkedHashSet<String>(libSettings.autoScanDirs);
    if (libSettings.autoScanRemovableMedia) {
        folders.addAll(MediaManager.getReadableMedia());
    }

    scanner.startScan(libSettings.allowedFileTypes, folders);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer myself. as per my requirement I wanted only the specified directory as the element of the Set. 
Actually i studied the concept "Set" in Java.

here what I did is:
just added two lines of code!!

```
folders.clear();
folders.add("/mnt/sdcard/chatter");
```